# python regular expressions index long string and eliminate all things between regular patterns A and B

Tags: python, regex

I have the following sentence where I want to get rid of everything with the format '(number)/(... ;  number)' :

> In all living organisms, from bacteria to man, DNA and chromatin are
>   invariably associated with binding proteins, which organize their
>   structure (1; 2 ;  3). Many of these architectural proteins are
>   molecular bridges that can bind at two or more distinct DNA sites to
>   form loops. For example, bacterial DNA is looped and compacted by the
>   histonelike protein H-NS, which has two distinct DNA-binding domains
>   (4). In eukaryotes, complexes of transcription factors and RNA
>   polymerases stabilize enhancer-promoter loops (5; 6; 7 ;  8), while
>   HP1 (9), histone H1 (10), and the polycomb-repressor complex PRC1/2
>   (11 ;  12) organize inactive chromatin. Proteins also bind to specific
>   DNA sequences to form larger structures, like nucleoli and the
>   histone-locus, or Cajal and promyeloleukemia bodies (13; 14; 15; 16;
>   17 ;  18). The selective binding of molecular bridges to active and
>   inactive regions of chromatin has also been highlighted as one
>   possible mechanism underlying the formation of topologically
>   associated domains (TADs)—regions rich in local DNA interactions (6; 8
>   ;  19).

I want it to be in the form:

> In all living organisms, from bacteria to man, DNA and chromatin are
>   invariably associated with binding proteins, which organize their
>   structure . Many of these architectural proteins are molecular bridges
>   that can bind at two or more distinct DNA sites to form loops. For
>   example, bacterial DNA is looped and compacted by the histonelike
>   protein H-NS, which has two distinct DNA-binding domains . In
>   eukaryotes, complexes of transcription factors and RNA polymerases
>   stabilize enhancer-promoter loops , while HP1 , histone H1 , and the
>   polycomb-repressor complex PRC1/2  organize inactive chromatin.
>   Proteins also bind to specific DNA sequences to form larger
>   structures, like nucleoli and the histone-locus, or Cajal and
>   promyeloleukemia bodies . The selective binding of molecular bridges
>   to active and inactive regions of chromatin has also been highlighted
>   as one possible mechanism underlying the formation of topologically
>   associated domains (TADs)—regions rich in local DNA interactions .

My attempt was as follows:

```
import re
x=re.sub(r'\(.+;  \d+\)', '', x) # eliminate brackets with multiple numbers
#### NOTE: there are 2 spaces between the last ';' and the last digit
x=re.sub(r'\d+\)', '', x) # eliminate brackets with single number
```

My output was this:

> In all living organisms, from bacteria to man, DNA and chromatin are
>   invariably associated with binding proteins, which organize their
>   structure .

So clearly my code is missing something. I thought that '(.+)' would identify all brackets containing non-arbitrary characters and then I could further specify that I want all the ones ending in a ';  number'.

I just want a flexible way of indexing a sentence at all places with '(number' and 'number)' and eliminate everything in between....

Comment: Your problem was one of "greed". By default, the `*` and `+` quantifiers in regular expressions are *greedy*. This means they match as many characters as possible, in order to complete the match. When you say `.*` or `.+`, it means *any character, lots of times,* and that includes the closing ')' in your brackets. So instead of matching `(abc)`, it actually might match `(abc)some text in the middle(def)`, since it goes as long as it can to the closing paren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use the pattern

```
re.sub('\([0-9; ]+\)', '', x)
```

which removes all parenthesis that contein at least a number, a ";" or a space.

I think it's not the case to use the r prefix.

Comment: The `r` prefix means "raw string".  Without it you need to *escape* the backslashes in your string.  (I think.  I may be wrong here.)

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry.
re.sub('\\\([0-9; ]+\\\)', '', x)
Right?
But I know also that with the r prefix the backslash will *remain* in the pattern, causing it not to match with the text

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern like `\(\d+(?:;\s?\d+\s?)*\)`, which matches an initial parentheses and digits `( <number>`, and then any possible repeating `; <number>`s that ends in `)`. [Test it.](https://regex101.com/r/ATyZ5y/1)

Or if you're feeling brave you can use `\([;\d\s]+\)` which just matches everything with digits/spaces/semicolons between two parentheses. [Test it.](https://regex101.com/r/pQwsIZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
r'\s\((\d+\s?;?\s?)+\)'
```

This regex will match one or more groups of numbers (followed by spaces/semicolons) inside of parenthesis.

There seems to always be a space before the collection of numbers, so matching that should help with the "trailing space".

Answer (score 0):

I found a glitch in your expected text, there's 1 space missing after `PRC1/2`. But this code works, with that space added back in:

```
text="""
In all living organisms, from bacteria to man, DNA and chromatin are invariably
associated with binding proteins, which organize their structure (1; 2 ; 3).
Many of these architectural proteins are molecular bridges that can bind at two
or more distinct DNA sites to form loops. For example, bacterial DNA is looped
and compacted by the histonelike protein H-NS, which has two distinct
DNA-binding domains (4). In eukaryotes, complexes of transcription factors and
RNA polymerases stabilize enhancer-promoter loops (5; 6; 7 ; 8), while HP1 (9),
histone H1 (10), and the polycomb-repressor complex PRC1/2 (11 ; 12) organize
inactive chromatin. Proteins also bind to specific DNA sequences to form larger
structures, like nucleoli and the histone-locus, or Cajal and promyeloleukemia
bodies (13; 14; 15; 16; 17 ; 18). The selective binding of molecular bridges to
active and inactive regions of chromatin has also been highlighted as one
possible mechanism underlying the formation of topologically associated domains
(TADs)—regions rich in local DNA interactions (6; 8 ; 19).
""".replace('\n', ' ')

expected="""
In all living organisms, from bacteria to man, DNA and chromatin are invariably
associated with binding proteins, which organize their structure . Many of
these architectural proteins are molecular bridges that can bind at two or more
distinct DNA sites to form loops. For example, bacterial DNA is looped and
compacted by the histonelike protein H-NS, which has two distinct DNA-binding
domains . In eukaryotes, complexes of transcription factors and RNA polymerases
stabilize enhancer-promoter loops , while HP1 , histone H1 , and the
polycomb-repressor complex PRC1/2  organize inactive chromatin. Proteins also
bind to specific DNA sequences to form larger structures, like nucleoli and the
histone-locus, or Cajal and promyeloleukemia bodies . The selective binding of
molecular bridges to active and inactive regions of chromatin has also been
highlighted as one possible mechanism underlying the formation of topologically
associated domains (TADs)—regions rich in local DNA interactions .
""".replace('\n', ' ')

import re

cites = r"\(\s*\d+(?:\s*;\s+\d+)*\s*\)"

edited = re.sub(cites, '', text)

i = 0
while i < len(edited):
    if edited[i] == expected[i]:
        print(edited[i], sep='', end='')
    else:
        print('[', edited[i], ']', sep='', end='')
    i+=1

print('')
```

The regex I'm using is `cites`, and it looks like this:

```
r"\(\s*\d+(?:\s*;\s+\d+)*\s*\)"
```

The syntax `r"..."` means "raw", which for our purposes means "leave backslashes alone!" It's what you should (nearly) always use for regexes.

The outer `\(` and `\)` match the actual parens in the citation.

The `\s*` matches zero or more "white-space" characters, which include spaces, tabs, and newlines.

The `\d+` matches one or more digits [0..9].

So to start with, there's a regex like:

```
\( \s* \d+ \s* \)
```

Which is just "parens around a number, maybe with spaces before or after."

The inner part,

```
(?:\s*;\s+\d+)*
```

says "don't capture": (?:...) is a non-capturing group, because we don't care about \1 or getting anything out of the pattern, we just want to delete it.

The `\s*;` matches optional spaces before a semicolon.

The `\s+\d+` matches *required* spaces before another number - you might have to make those optional spaces if you have something like "(1;3;5)".

The `*` after the non-capturing group means zero or more occurrences.

Put it all together and you have:

```
open-paren
optional spaces
number
followed by zero or more of:
    optional spaces
    semicolon
    required spaces
    number
optional spaces
close-paren
```